# IOS rotate device without rotation animation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiview, rotation

What would be the correct way to achieve an effect similar to the one in the standard iPod app of the iPhone - when the device is rotated to landscape mode, the view changes to cover flow, but the type of transition is fade and not the rotating screen?

This is how I am loading the modal view:

```
- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        carouselView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentModalViewController:carouselView animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Andrius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I later found that it is more stable to use this solution:

In the parent view controller (in my case it is tab view controller) viewdidload method add this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

and then add this method:

```
- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification {     

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation) && !self.modalViewController) {
        [self presentModalViewController:carouselView animated:YES];
        [Globals sharedGlobals].startedAtLandscape = YES;
    }

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation) && self.modalViewController) {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
        [Globals sharedGlobals].startedAtLandscape = NO;
    }
}
```

And finally if you want to prevent the rotation animation, modify this method like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: presentModalViewController is deprecated.